# Trying to retrieve rows where an id does not exist for a user

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query that returns only the users where they do
not have a role as 1.

The table columns are roleid, userid, usertype. The userid has an entry for each roleid. So for example:

```
roleid     userid
  1           323    
  3           323
  4           323
  6           323
  7           323
  10          323    
  3           324
  4           324
  6           324
  7           324
  10          324
```

Everytime I try this it just takes out the row where the roleid is 1 but I need a whole user i.e 323 not to show as it has 1.

Would really appreciate help with this.

Thanks

Edit:

```
select * from usersroles where userid in (
select userid from uprofiles where networkid in 
(select network_id from network where usertype in (469,467,466,468))) and roleid !=1;
```

I am using the above but this returns the users without roleid 1 but still returns the users with the other roles. I want the query to only return users that do not have 1.

Comment: can you show us some code to better understand what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Is it so EASY???

```
select distinct userid from table where UserID <> 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You either need the exists clause:

```
select userid from users 
where not exists (select * from userroles where userid = users.userid and roleid = 1);
```

Or you subtract the set of users with roleid 1 from the set of all users:

```
select userid from users
minus 
select userid from userroles where roleid = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `users` table, than you could do:

```
select ID -- other relevant user fields here
from users
where ID not in (select userId from userRoles where roleId = 1)
```

If you do not have a separate table for the users (i.e. the `userId` field is not a foreign key), than you could do:

```
select distinct userId 
from userRoles
where userId not in (select userId from userRoles where roleId = 1)
```

In both cases, the subquery `select userId from userRoles where roleId = 1` will give you a list of users that do have the `1` role, and you just need to make sure that ID of the user is not in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have edited your request, here is your corrected select statement:

```
select * from usersroles where userid in 
(
  select userid from uprofiles where networkid in 
  (
    select network_id from network where usertype in (469,467,466,468)
  )
)
and userid not in
(
  select userid from usersroles where roleid =1
);
```

Or:

```
select * from usersroles where userid in 
(
  select userid from uprofiles where networkid in 
  (
    select network_id from network where usertype in (469,467,466,468)
  )
  minus
  select userid from usersroles where roleid =1
);
```